# Difficult Inequality

Tags: inequalities

Suppose $x,y\geq 0$ and $b,c,d\geq 1$ are integers. Prove or find a counterexample to the following inequality
$$
\frac{1}{1+\frac{b+d}{\sqrt{x^{2}+c^{2}}}} + \frac{1}{1+\frac{c+d}{\sqrt{y^{2}+b^{2}}}}\geq \frac{1}{1+\frac{d}{\sqrt{(x+b)^{2}+(y+c)^{2}}}}.
$$

Comment: If the inequality is true, then it also holds for any real numbers $b,c,d>0$. This is because multiplying $x,y$ by some integer $n\geq 1$ has the same effect as dividing $b,c,d$ by $n$, so the inequality holds when $b,c,d>0$ are rational, hence by continuity also when they are real.

Comment:     why           ?

Comment: Are you asking me? What I said is simple algebra.

Comment: no - i was asking the OP

Comment: It looks exactly like a typical math. contest inequality and, as such, it is of easy to medium difficulty (that by itself is quite a hint). Since I strongly suspect that some cheating is taking place, I'll not post an answer until I am convinced that I'm wrong here. I'll abstain from voting to close though because I do not have an irrefutable proof of my suspicion either.

Comment: @Anthony Quas: I am familiar with what the OP is asking, but I don't know the answer. The inequality is obtained when considering whether e certain distance function on discrete sets is a metric, i.e., whether it obeys the triangle inequality, for the case p=2. @ fedja: So it does not come from any contest, nor is there any "cheating" whatever that means.

Comment: in general, since this is a math research web site, we ask people who pose questions to give enough context so that we know it's not a homework question or a competition question

Comment: I agree with @Anthony -- the question looks very similar to a slew of contest problems.

Comment: Now that it's answered, casting the final vote to close. If it does turn out to be a contest (and that's what it looks like), this is serious cheating; if not, the OP has an answer.

Answer (score 11):

OK, I'll take kodlu's word as a proof this time. :).

Let $u=\sqrt{x^2+c^2}$, $v=\sqrt{y^2+b^2}$, $w=\sqrt{(x+b)^2+(y+c)^2}$.
We need to show that 
$$
\frac{u}{u+b+d}+\frac{v}{v+c+d}\ge \frac{w}{w+d}
$$
Note that $w\le u+v$ (triangle inequality on the plane) and that $t\mapsto \frac{t}{t+d}$ is increasing in $t$, so it will suffice to show that
$$
\frac{u}{u+b+d}+\frac{v}{v+c+d}\ge \frac{u+v}{u+v+d}.
$$
However, $b\le v$ and $c\le u$, so the LHS is at least
$$
\frac{u}{u+v+d}+\frac{v}{v+u+d}= \frac{u+v}{u+v+d}.
$$

As I said, I wouldn't be surprised to see it on some decent high school math. contest.

Comment: @ fedja: thanks, it is indeed straightforward.